# console.log() misbehaviour with simple JSON calls

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, console.log

I initialize the array historicalData=[0,0,...,0], then process a few JSON files and fill the array with the result. Console.log-ing the array content gives [0,0,...,0].
But if I run console.log(historicalData) from the firebug console, I get the correct content. Why?

```
   var d = new Date();
   var m = d.getMonth();
   var y = d.getYear() +1900;
   var y2 = y-1;
   var historicalData=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];    //init step
   var counter = 11;
   var i;

   for (i = m; i!= m || y!=y2; i--) {
    if (i==0) {
     i=12;
     y = y-1;
    }
    var src = "http://192.168.183.135/incidents/affectedUsersJSON.php?month=".concat(i).concat("&year=").concat(y);;
    (function (i,counter,historicalData) {
     $.getJSON(src, function funct(data) {
      count = Object.keys(data).length;
      if (count ==1 ) {
        historicalData[counter] = 0         //filling the array
      }
      else {
       historicalData[counter] = count;     //filling the array
      }
      counter = counter-1;
     })
    }(i,counter,historicalData));
   counter = counter-1;
   }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="users">Users</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(historicalData);            //console.log-ing the results: I get only ZEROS!
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After getting disappointed by the output in the console, I run "console.log(historicalData)" from the console itself and.. I get the CORRECT results. 
Why?

Comment: [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson) -> [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) -> [Ajax](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/), [What's AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the JSON call has not been returned completely. You need to setup a call back

```
.done(function( data ) {
```

put your console.log call on the result inside here and you should get the result that you expect.

For you ref

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: where should I put this, as I'd need to call it after all cicles in the for loop are through?

Comment: Put this inside your getJSON function
    $.getJSON(src, function funct(data) {
    .done(function(data) {
    // put your code here
    
    });
    });

Look at the link I gave you earlier
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

You're having a timing issue here. When you make an Ajax call to a website to update a variable, there's a bit of delay while the web browser attempts to load that page. So for the first few seconds of your page being loaded, historicalData will still be all 0s. Since you call console.log() on the data immediately when the page is loading, the Ajax call will almost never be completed in time.

The function that you have written inside of your `$.getJSON` call will not be executed until after a result comes back from the web server. So if you need to do something with the result of the Ajax call, do it inside that function so you can be guaranteed that your data will already exist.